# Grant "Log on as a service" permission AND service Logon Account during installation(Installshield 2010)

Tags: service, installation, installshield, installshield-2010

I`m developing install application via Installshield Basic MSI Project

1. I have a little problem when granting "Log on as a service" permission
   (Control panel -> Administrative tools -> Local Security Settings)

In Windows server 2003, NTRights.exe works fine.

In Windows server 2008 and 2008 R2, NTRight.exe also works fine but "NTRights.exe" is just part of "Windows server 2003 Toolkit"

I want to use another method.
Can Anyone do same thing using another way?

1. In a Service Panel, I have to set Logon account and password using end user input.

But Installshield supports just fixed id, password. It cannot be used.

How can i do this to set logon account?
Logon account information should be provided during installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this article.  Once you understand it, just change it up a bit by using information from the second link.

[Augmenting InstallShield using Windows Installer XML - Certificates](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2011/01/augmenting-installshield-using-windows.html)

[User Element (Util Extension)](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_user.htm)

Another approach using a WiX DTF custom action can be found at:

[Different year, Same Problem...](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2008/09/different-year-same-problem.html)

Comment: hmm I tried your advice, but it cannot be done.i need to pass an account and a password to wix merge module.

Comment: Did you solve this? I also need to set "log on as a service" permissions on the username and password that the user provides during installation so that the Service successfully start.

Comment: @sjuu why did you accept this answer if it didn't solve your problem?!

Comment: He probably accepted years later and didn't leave another comment.  I get that a lot.