# How to grant an existing user 'Log on as  a service' permissions?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

How can I set a user to be granted with 'Log on as a service' permissions?

Is there a native way to do so or a custom action?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grant "Log on as a service" permission AND service Logon Account during installation(Installshield 2010)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787135/grant-log-on-as-a-service-permission-and-service-logon-account-during-installa)

Comment: Take a look at the second link in Christopher's answer - the `User` element in WiX has `LogonAsService` attribute. Set it to `yes` to achieve your goal. You might also want to set `CreateUser` to `no`, if you just need to modify existing account.